# Dynamically created tabs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I create a simple page builder that can create tabs .
I use JQuery UI to create tabs

when user clicks on create tab, he will face with a modal pop up that includes title and content and after completing them he can click on create tab (with #tab id) and he can create multiple tabs with same form and button

JS :

```js
  var num_tabs = 0;
  var elementIdforOneRound;
  var first = -1;
  $("#tab").click(function() { // fire by clicking on add button in tab modal

    if (first != SelectedElement) { // create tab panel
      var item = "<div id='elem-" + elementId + "' onclick='updateSelectedElement(event," + elementId + ");'><ul></ul></div>";
      $(SelectedElement).append(item); // append created item to SelectedElement (selected column)
      $("div#elem-" + elementId + "").tabs();
      elementIdforOneRound = elementId;
      elementId++;
    }
    var title = document.getElementById('tb-title').value;
    var content = document.getElementById('tb-content').value;
    num_tabs = $("div#elem-" + elementIdforOneRound + " ul li").length + 1;
    $("div#elem-" + elementIdforOneRound + " ul").append(
      "<li><a href='#tab" + num_tabs + "'>" + title + "</a></li>"
    );
    $("div#elem-" + elementIdforOneRound + "").append(
      "<div id='tab" + num_tabs + "'>" + content + "</div>"
    );
    $("div#elem-" + elementIdforOneRound + "").tabs("refresh");
    first = SelectedElement;
  });
```

the problem is that, tabs work fine when the user adds them to page but when he export the page (I have an export button that give the html file to user) the tabs in that page, doesn't work . code for created tabs is the same in both pages !

```html
<div id="elem-1" onclick="updateSelectedElement(event,1);" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="box-shadow: rgb(185, 185, 185) 2px 2px 1px;">
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tab1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#tab1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">aaaa</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tab2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true"><a href="#tab2" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">bbbb</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">aaaa</div>
  <div id="tab2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">bbbb</div>
</div>
```

note : I put created page beside the page builder page (for proper accessing to css and js files )

Comment: SelectedElement is a global var that keep current selected column (in page builder)

Comment: Do you have relative paths to your css and javascript files in your html? Unless all paths in the html are absolute paths to files hosted somewhere on the web, only giving the user the html will not work. You would need to bundle up the css and javascript with the html in a .zip file or the like, and make sure the directory structure aligns with the paths you have to your css and javascript in your html. Then, when the user clicks the export button, you could create the .zip file and let them download it.

Comment: @AndrewMairose yes they are relative and the html file has access to them , it's the reason that confused me !

Answer (score 0):

Since your html file has relative paths, giving the user just the HTML file will not work.

When you use a relative path, the browser will look in the same directory as the HTML file when you attempt to reference other files. So, say you have this in the `<head>` on your HTML page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tabs.css">
```

The browser will look for a directory called `css` in the same directory as the HTML file, and it will try to find `tabs.css` inside that directory.

If your CSS file is not where the browser expects it to be, then none of the styles in that CSS file will be applied to the page.

So, when your users download just the HTML, they will have `yoursite.html` in their `Downloads` folder. And when `yoursite.html` tries to load, say `yourcss.css`, it won't find that file in their `Downloads` folder.

For the desired behavior of your export button to work, you have a few options:

1. You could use only absolute paths to any CSS or javascript in your HTML
2. You could put your CSS and javascript code directly in the page inside of `<style>` and `<script>` tags

OR

3. When the user clicks export, you could bundle up all the resources needed by the page into a zip file or the like and then let the user download that.

**EDIT:**

Another alternative option would be to remove the export feature all together, and rather instruct your users on how to use their browser to get the full page content themselves. Most modern browsers will let you simply right-click anywhere on the page and click 'Save As' or 'Save Page As', and then select a destination. When you do this, it will save the HTML file to the destination location, as well as another folder that contains all the necessary CSS, javascript, etc.

Comment: #3 ... yes that sound's good :) how can I deliver a bundle of all resources to user ?

Comment: You would most likely need to do that on the back end. I don't think there is a way to do that in just pure javascript. You might want to ask a new question for that, and include what technology, if any, that you are using for a back end.